# Substituting limit in integral bound and integrand random variable

Tags: probability-theory, limits, improper-integrals, expected-value

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable taking non-negative values only. To prove: $\mathbb{E}(X)=\int_0^\infty (1-F_X(x)) dx$ where $F_X$ is the distribution function of $X$.
I have derived the following expression: $\mathbb{E}(X)=\lim_{t\to\infty} \int_0^t (1-\frac{1}{F_X(t)} F_X(x))dx$.
My question is: can I replace the upper bound with $\infty$ and substitute $F_X(t)=1$, als $\lim_{t\to\infty} F_X(t)=1$? If so, why does this work?

Comment: Yes, because for every $x \in (0,\infty)$ the function $g_x(t) := (1 - \frac{F_X(x)}{F_X(t)}) 1_{\{x \le t\}}$ converges to $1 - F_X(x)$ as $t \to \infty$ in a non-decreasing manner (i.e $g_x(t_1) \le g_x(t_2)$ for $t_1 \le t_2$). Hence, by Monotone Convergence Theorem you can pass to the limit as $t \to +\infty$.  Just out of curiosity, how did you obtain your expression? Asking, cause probably the most standard way of proving $\mathbb EX = \int_0^\infty (1-F_X(x))dx$ is to note by Fubinii that $\mathbb EX = \mathbb E[ \int_0^\infty 1_{\{x \le X\}} dx] = \int_0^\infty \mathbb P(X > x)dx.$